# What are the two other Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$ besides $H=\{(1),(12),(34),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),(1324),(1423)\}.$ A different method please?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

Please, please I ask that you do not refer me to the question that has been answered already: Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4.$ I do not understand the bisections and what they are describing in that explaination.

Rather, I need help with a different method to finding the other 2 subgroups by way of using $\sigma H \sigma^{-1},$ and using the fact that 
$\sigma H \sigma^{-1},= (\sigma(a1); \sigma(a2); . . . ; \sigma(ak)).$

I am just having a hard time picking an element in $S_4$ and using this formula to produce something that doesnʻt look like $H$.

Comment: Imagine a square with vertices labeled 1,2,3,4. The dihedral group of that square is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$. There are three distinct subgroups of this kind, corresponding to how we order the vertices. Specifically, if we enumerate in clockwise order, then the enumerations $1234$, $1243$, and $1423$ yield three distinct subgroups.

Comment: I see....that makes sense in the grander scheme of things, but I am still confused a bit. If the H subgroup given above is a  Sylow 2-subgroup of s4, donʻt the others have to have 8 elements also? Are you saying one of those enumerations represents H?

Comment: For a specific conjugation example, note that the $4$-cycle $(1234)$ is in the first subgroup mentioned in my previous comment, and $(1243)$ is in the second subgroup. And we have $(1243) = (34)(1234)(34)$.

Comment: The subgroup corresponding to the first ordering 1234 is $H = \{1, (1234), (13)(24), (1432), (24), (14)(23), (13), (12)(34)\}$. The first four of these elements are rotations, and the other four are reflections. You can obtain the other two subgroups by conjugation. They are $(34)H(34)$ and $(243)H(234)$.

Comment: Oh wow yeah I get it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

They do "look like" $H$, because they are isomorphic to $H$.

To find them,  just play around with some elements $g$ of $S_4$, computing, say, $g(12)g^{-1}$, until you get something not in $H$.

Once you find such a $g$, one of the other Sylow subgroups will be $gHg^{-1}$.

Of course, if $g$ consists of cycles disjoint from $(12)$, you'll just get $(12)$ back again.  So choose something else, until you find one that works.

This works because conjugation is an automorphism.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence for I think that addresses the OPs confusion. I may be wrong though.